# What is the minimal working IVsTextViewCreationListener implementation?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, mef, visual-studio-extensions

I created a VISX project, and wrote this piece of code:

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextManager.Interop;
using System.ComponentModel.Composition;

namespace MyExtension
{
    [Export(typeof(IVsTextViewCreationListener))]
    public class Main : IVsTextViewCreationListener
    {
        public void VsTextViewCreated(IVsTextView textViewAdapter)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

If I put a breakpoint inside the `VsTextViewCreated` method, Visual Studio informs me that it will never be hit. Opening files in the second instance of Visual Studio that launches in the debugger indeed does not trigger it.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

You need to specify ContentType and TextViewRole for your class:

```
[Microsoft.VisualStudio.Utilities.ContentType("text")]
[Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Editor.TextViewRole(Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Editor.PredefinedTextViewRoles.Editable)]
```

Also don't forget to declare a MefComponent asset in your extension manifest:

[image]

And make sure in .csproj:

```
<IncludeAssemblyInVSIXContainer>true</IncludeAssemblyInVSIXContainer>
```

Comment: It was the MefComponent that I was missing. Thanks.